# Hopeless with mounting windows harddisk on ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, mount, hard-drive

I had windows 8 in this laptop and I mistakenly wiped it all clean when installing linux in it. I pulled out the harddisk here and tried it out on windows 8, the file explorer didn't show it. But I ran some recovery tools like Icarerecovery and grabbed some important deleted data from my laptop's harddisk which I had to copy on my desktop computer's harddisk with WINDOWS 8 on it. 
Now I can't copy them back to the laptop's harddisk because all the partitions are ext4 and windows doesn't even bother showing it. I know, I know the ext2pdf and the like of those programs. I've tried them, still windows explorer just won't show those files.
So, I got a SATA to USB converter, pulled out the harddisk from desktop computer and plugged them on this Ubuntu. So far, it detects them as USB flash drives but it fails to mount them no matter what. I have that ntfs-3g here installed on ubuntu still the following dialogue pops up when I click on the drives

![img]http://i58.tinypic.com/2igzyur.png

I've tried everything and now my data is stuck in this other hard disk that I can't access on my Ubuntu, neither can I access the ubuntu harddisk on windows. That is some really private stuff, and the other computer is a family computer. For the time being, I've that recovered data hidden with some folder locker in windows but I want it here. I can't use Google Drive or some online service because it's too large for that. Please help me out. So many ebooks, that I'd read in free time, and a lot more that I can no longer access.

Comment: PS I've tried to access them booting the Linux livedisc too. No luck

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I just did this on the weekend for my father in law and it worked like a charm. Hopefully it will work for you as well.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions

Comment: Tried already. Nautilus doesn't even show those devices.

Comment: Tried those steps. 
<pre>
robbino@robbino-Latitude-E6410:~$ sudo mount -a
[sudo] password for robbino: 
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
robbino@robbino-Latitude-E6410:~$ 

</pre>

Comment: Did you try to do this from terminal? Try starting form the manual configuration on the help.

Comment: Already did, dude. No luck. I wonder if there is a way to transfer those files from Windows to Linux through LAN as the two are connected through the same  router

Comment: Have you tried looking [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu)?